# Do a pop up with a svg file and the pop up call then the html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, popup

I´m working in a project, and they want that call a pop up with a svg, i have the code of svg file, in html, and in this file i have some links, and when you click the link, this information go to the father html page!
If someone help me, i really thanks!

PD: Sorry for my english -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `window.opener` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.opener) and use that to affect your window from the popup.